# ref0 not resolved by petitparser

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub, petitparser

[petitparser](https://pub.dev/packages/petitparser) is a parser generator written in [dart](https://dart.dev) to be used e.g. in [Flutter](https://events.flutter.dev).

According to [this page](https://github.com/petitparser/dart-petitparser), [petitparser](https://pub.dev/packages/petitparser) allows to use `ref0` to reference the current parse class.

In the section **Using Grammar Definitions** you read this statement:

> To refer to a production defined in the same definition use ***[ref0]***
> with the function reference as the argument.

According to the docs, you have to define this dependecy to  the **petitpackage** package

```
dependencies:
  petitparser: ^4.0.2
```

and include this:

```
import 'package:petitparser/petitparser.dart';
```

Unfortunately, `ref0` and `ref1` do not resolve. **Why?**

In case the **package and the sources are out of sync**: Does a simple way to replace `ref0` by equivalent valid code exist?

Additionally, I didn't find `ref0` / `ref1` in the [API-documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/petitparser/latest/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referring to the documentation on GitHub, which is the development version of PetitParser (that is the upcoming version of PetitParser 4.1.0). Please refer to the documentation of the PetitParser version you have installed, i.e https://pub.dev/packages/petitparser/versions/4.0.2.

Regarding your question: Unfortunately 4.0.2 did not document `ParserDefinition` in the tutorial. If you read the latest documentation you can replace all references of `ref0`, `ref1`, ... with `ref`. The number suffix was added for 4.1.0 to allow stricter typing.

Comment: Ah. Therefore I can't compile the GitHub published samples with the resolved 4.0.2 package?

Comment: I've added a second part to my answer that explains how you could fix the tutorial: replace `ref0`, `ref1`, ... with `ref`.